# What happens when you discharge a capacitor in series with another capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, series

I have been told that this is a bad situation, so I made a circuit diagram. Unfortunately I am not sure the simulator is going to tell me everything that I need to know.

[image]

Let's say I have a circuit like this. C2 and C1 are charged to 5 V in series, meaning each carries about 2.5 V. The 5 V charger is then disconnected from the circuit.

What happens when -

1. R1 > R2 (5 kΩ, 50 kΩ)
2. R2 > R1 (50 kΩ, 5 kΩ)
3. R1 and R2 are both significantly smaller (5 Ω, 50 Ω)
4. The capacitors are significantly larger (>10 F, >10 F)
5. In what scenarios is this dangerous, potentially causing damage to one of the capacitors?

Comment: Who told you it's "dangerous"?  Note as shown, you will NOT have 2.5V on each cap.  There will be something much much smaller on C1 and nearly the full 5V on C2

Comment: Which simulator are you using?

Comment: I fixed the cap but I don't have the rep to upvote. I'm using KICAD!

Comment: @KyleB I may have made a dumb substitution... R1 is actually an IC that uses about 1mA of current and has a voltage range of like 2V - 6V... I swapped it as a resistor here.... So you're saying the IC won't even be powered because of this?

Comment: @KyleB I heard it was dangerous to have capacitors in series and discharge their current separately (like above). But it must only be true if you discharge a lot at a time, quickly?

Comment: Have you made other substitutions?  Please describe the actual situation instead of a simplification.

Comment: That's really the only substitution.

Comment: Since this looks like a homework question we expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve it yourself, then ask a **specific** question.

Comment: _”Unfortunately I am not sure the simulator is going to tell me everything that I need to know.”_ Polar opposite! Simulation is a necessary tool and a good way to learn.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It looks like a homework question but it's not. I just generalized a simple problem to refresh my memory. It doesn't fit my practical application exactly, but is there any reason my mind should be blanking on this simplification? No way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C2 and C1 are charged to 5V in series, meaning each carries about
> 2.5V.

This is only true if the charging voltage is not applied for a very long time, because R1 slowly discharges C1 to 0 V and charges C2 to 5 V. After about 2 minutes of continuous charging the voltage on C2 will increase to ~3.0 V. If it is rated for eg. 5.5 V then it should be fine, but if it is only rated for 2.5 V then it could be damaged.

When the charging voltage is removed you have another problem - the reduced discharge rate of C2 will cause it to hold its voltage for longer, driving C1 negative after ~17 minutes and reaching -0.2 V by ~26 minutes. Polarized capacitors do not like having reverse voltage on them.

If you recharge before the reversal occurs it won't stop the imbalance, which will continue to get worse. It can only be 'reset' by waiting long enough for both capacitors to fully discharge.

A circuit *might* be OK with this behavior, but in a typical super-capacitor application (where two are wired in series to increase the voltage rating) it's bad - possibly even dangerous.

Comment: Zener diodes on the capacitors might be a good idea, but 2.5V zeners are uncommon and tend to have a soft "knee". Four silicon diodes in series should limit voltage to about 2.4-2.8 V, and another diode (perhaps Schottky) would provide some reverse protection.

Comment: @PStechPaul better than a 2.5V Zener is a 2.495V TL431.

Comment: Well, that can only sink 100 mA. You may need to handle several amps when dealing with large capacitors.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been told that this is a bad situation, so I made a circuit diagram.

Watch this when the power supply is a PWM voltage.
Note that **I added a 100m Ohm** for internal impedance of the power supply ... for **limiting currents**.

> The capacitors are significantly larger (>10 F, >10 F)
> In what scenarios is this dangerous, potentially causing damage to one of the capacitors?

See also the "currents" as @PStechPaul pointed out.
As we don't know HOW this circuit is used ...
**The more bad scenario is this one** ...
One can note the **50 A charge current and 30 A discharge (and here it is limited !)**.
**So, yes. Your configuration is Bad.**

[image]

Comment: Whoever downvoted should know how to read between the lines ...